# Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string on line 52

Tags: php, mysql, web

my error is

> `"Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string"`

my code error line is :

```
$type = queryMysql("SELECT `type` FROM `register` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
echo "$type";
if ($type == "admin")
        {
            die("Welcome back Admin $name <br> you can go to the control panel by clicking <a href='#'>here</a>");
        }
        elseif ($type == "user")
            echo "Welcome back user $name.";
```

the "type" is defined in the database as "admin" or "user", and the error line is the "`echo '$type';"`

Comment: What is `queryMysql()`?

Comment: that isn't how it works. You need to loop over successful results.

Comment: as Fred said, you need to loop trough the queryset to print out the contents. Take a look at [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) and [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your function `queryMysql` does not return a string, but it returns a `myslqi_result`. You should treat it as such, and not as a string

Comment: what do you advise me to do

Comment: read the manual of mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php